# Multi Variate Breusch Godfrey LM Autocorrelation test for VAR in statsmodels python?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

Is there a way to do multi variate Bruesch Godfrey Lagrange Multiplier residual serial correlation tests for vector autoregressions (VAR) using statsmodels? I would like to get the same output as Eviews in View > Residual Tests> Autocorrleation LM Test

[image: Eviews Output I'm Tying to Replicate]

I have tried using the acorr_breusch_godfrey from stats models but it doesn't seem to be giving me outputs. Am I misparameterizing this? Or do I need to loop through the variables some how?

Below is an example using OLS (works) and the second one is VAR (doesn't work).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import acorr_breusch_godfrey

data = pd.read_csv('http://web.pdx.edu/~crkl/ceR/data/cjx.txt', sep='\s+', index_col='YEAR', nrows=39)

X = np.log(data.X)
L = np.log(data.L1)
K = np.log(data.K1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'L': L, 'K': K})

# OLS Regression
model_ols = sm.OLS.from_formula('X~L+K', df).fit()
# print(model_ols.summary())
print(sm.stats.diagnostic.acorr_breusch_godfrey(model_ols))

# Vector Auto Regression
model_var = VAR(endog=df[['L','K']],exog=df['X']).fit(maxlags=2)
# print(results_var.summary())
sm.stats.diagnostic.acorr_breusch_godfrey(model_var,nlags=15)
```

For the last one I've also tried the below to no avail:

```
sm.stats.diagnostic.acorr_breusch_godfrey(model_var.resid.loc[:,0],nlags=15)
```

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.acorr_breusch_godfrey.html